# What are the options to develop Fully Offline Global Map for MS Pixelsense with pushpins

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pixelsense

Planning to develop an application ( Fully offline ) that shows global map with pushpins on 100+ places. Those places should have zoom enabled. Kindly advise what sdk or controls are available for this to be developed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no free SDK to do something like this, you would actually have to pay for map data and you are not allowed to use google or bing map tiles in your own application without using the respective APIs...

There are applications which provides this kind of stuff like http://www.arcgis.com/features/, but as I said, you'll have to pay for licenses.